# «Побыть дома не слабо!» Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

«Побыть дома не слабо!» Название статьи. Стоит ли ставить тире перед «не слабо», может, интонационное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92) (Розенталь)

> 5. При наличии *паузы* между главными членами предложения тире ставится между подлежащим, выраженным неопределенной формой глагола, и сказуемым, выраженным предикативным наречием на ***-о*** (категорией состояния): ***Уступить*** — ***позорно*** (Тендр.); *Это очень **несносно** — **переезжать*** (Гонч.); *Это **ужасно** — **струсить** в последний момент; Это чертовски **весело** — **кататься** на лодке* [ср. без паузы: ***Кататься** на лодке **весело**; **Судить** человека в немилости очень **легко*** (Л. Т.)].

Так что возможны оба варианта: с тире и без тире.

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:
> <...>
> 3) если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание ***не***...

Но и в этом случае логическое и интонационное подчеркивание сказуемого с помощью тире — не ошибка.